# Using the_content with data attribute

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hello guys I'm trying to get content of my posts into data attribute because I want store it there for later use with JQ. This is my code.

```
<div class="test" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-content="<?php the_content() ?>"></div>
```

I'm doing this with my slider and when I try it instead of just storing the value in data-content it actually outputs it on my page. I have also tried using `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()` ,but then it stores no value and I have also tried `data-content="<?php echo get_the_content() ?>"` but this also outputs data directly just like with `the_content()`.

Is there way to store value of `the_content()` into data attribute and use it later with JQ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because `the_content()` function prints the HTML tags as well.

Try to use `esc_attr()` function to escape it.

`data-content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_content() ) ?>"`

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Is there any way to do this and keep the html structure of the_content ?

Comment: Try this: `esc_attr( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ) );`